# TypeError: 'bytearray' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-bytearray

I want to send audio data over HTTP, but I don't understand why I'm getting this exception:

> ```
> Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 59976)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
>     self.finish_request(request, client_address)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
>     self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
>     self.handle()
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 418, in handle
>     self.handle_one_request()
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 406, in handle_one_request
>     method()
>   File "/home/vivanov/temp.py", line 113, in do_GET
>     data.append(bytearray(stream.read(CHUNK)))
> TypeError: 'bytearray' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
> ```

The problem seems to have to do with passing values to `wfile.write`.

How can I resolve the issue?

This is the code I have:

```py
class ChunkingRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    ALWAYS_SEND_SOME = False
    ALLOW_GZIP = False
    protocol_version = 'HTTP/1.1'
    def do_GET(self):
        ae = self.headers.get('accept-encoding') or ''

        # send some headers
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'audio/x-wav')

        self.end_headers()

        data = bytearray(wav_header)
        data.append(bytearray(stream.read(CHUNK)))
        print(data)
        self.wfile.write(b"%X\r\n%s\r\n" % (len(data), data))

        while True:
            data = bytearray(stream.read(CHUNK))
            self.wfile.write(b"%X\r\n%s\r\n" % (len(data), data))

        # send the chunked trailer
        self.wfile.write('0\r\n\r\n')
```

Comment: Please share any code and data necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've just put my code in a separate post below because it is a big snippet.

Comment: Your error message contains a stack trace. It will tell you what triggered the error. If you look at it, it does not say that calling `wfile.write()` triggered it. Instead, it says you passed a `bytearray` into `data.append()`, and that's the problem. `bytearray`s act like lists, here's [the ordinary operations you can do on lists and bytearrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable)

Comment: @DanGetz , I've added the code I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is the final code I end up working, might be useful for someone:

```py
class ChunkingRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    ALWAYS_SEND_SOME = False
    ALLOW_GZIP = False
    protocol_version = 'HTTP/1.1'
    def do_GET(self):
        ae = self.headers.get('accept-encoding') or ''

        # send some headers
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'audio/x-wav')

        self.end_headers()

        data = []
        for i in wav_header:
            data.append(int(i))
        for i in stream.read(CHUNK):
            data.append(int(i))
        self.wfile.write(bytearray(data))

        while True:
            data = []
            for i in stream.read(CHUNK):
                data.append(int(i))
            self.wfile.write(bytearray(data))

        # send the chunked trailer
        self.wfile.write('0\r\n\r\n')
```

Answer (score 9):

Despite its name, if you want to append more than one element at a time to a list-like object in Python, you can't use the `append` method. A `bytearray` acts like a list of bytes, so the way to append or concatenate another `bytearray` onto it is with the `extend` method, or `+=`:

```
data += bytearray(...)
#  OR
data.extend(bytearray(...))
```

In fact, if whatever you're adding to your `bytearray` is already something that can be passed into the `bytearray()` constructor, you likely don't need to wrap it in a `bytearray()`. For example, `bytes` objects (like `b'something'`) can be added directly:

```
data += b'something'
```

---

Once you fix that line of your code, you may have problems on other lines. For example, if `wfile.write` takes `bytes`, then sending it a unicode string like `'0\r\n\r\n'` will probably error; it looks like you meant to write `b'0\r\n\r\n'`.